# How to keep Rake::Task[:environment] always in memory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I have a bunch of cron jobs which run almost every 2 minutes. I am looking for a way to keep Rake::Task[:environment] always in memory so that I don't have to load it explicitly everytime I execute some models dependent rake tasks.
How can I go about doing this?

Comment: Have you tried [`zeus`](https://github.com/burke/zeus)? `zeus rake` is pretty quick.

Answer (score 0):

Johnsyweb's comment about zeus is a good one.  You might also consider a background processing solution like sidekiq.  http://sidekiq.org

Depending on how many a "bunch" is anyway.